# Change default Win explorer "view" for a portable media device

Tags: windows-7

In normal Windows 7 file explorer windows, it is possible through the [Tools > Folder Options] menu to choose a default way for all folders to be displayed (i.e. list/tiles/details/etc).

When connecting a portable media device and browsing the internal storage, that menu is not available.  If the device has 100 folders, every single one defaults to "tile" view.  Is there any way for me to change the default?

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell]
"FolderType"="NotSpecified" 

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}]
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  Could you give more info on exactly what you're doing?  This seemed to work at first and made my portable device default to "detail view" for every folder.  But it also did the same thing for all internal disks in my PC, which I did not want.  When I reverted them back to list view as I prefer, the mobile device reverted back to icon view and refused to remember future changes (unless, I assume, I edited the registry again).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is what you're aiming for, you can access the same menu through the right-click menu on your portable device.

[image]

You may also want to try customizing the folder so that it can be optimized to be viewed for certain file types.

[image]

Comment: I should have been more clear... the way I do it on a normal drive is to use `Tools > View > Apply to Folders` as a way to propagate down through all child folders recursively.  However, that button is greyed out for my portable media device!  Also, the "customize" menu you show is not available for the device or any of root folders within, no matter how deep I go.

Comment: Interesting. I normally do it that way and I've never had any problems. Also, are you right-clicking on the actual portable device itself? What's the portable device, BTW (not sure if it matters, anyway)?

Comment: It's a Nexus 7 (the newest one), and I've tried it on the device itself, the first root folder within ("internal storage") and even folders much deeper in that tree such as the DCIM folder which holds the digital camera shots.